# Copy S3 objects in the different region bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am copying S3 objects from one Bucket A (region: us-west-2) to another Bucket B( region: us-east-1), While doing so, I am getting these errors: The bucket is in this region: us-east-1. Please use this region to retry the request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 301; Error Code: PermanentRedirect; Request ID: 8A8C33763F67F1EE; S3 Extended Request ID: y2IHUTD6Fsi3aNLLJCWX4ZvnaDM9kxxk8yuJIUXZGBoIkWH9GQxHiJFog5No6pd1S4WK6cHIT14=; Proxy: null): com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception

This is how I have created S3Client:

```
 public AmazonS3 getAmazonS3(final AppConfigTree appConfigTree) {
return AmazonS3ClientBuilder
        .standard()
        .withClientConfiguration(s3ClientConfiguration())
        .withRegion(appConfigTree.findString("us-west-2"))
        .build();}
```

S3 Copy Operation :

```
private void copyObjects(final ObjectListing objects, final String srcBucket, final String srcPath,
                     final String destBucket, final String destPath) {

log.info(String.format("Copying %d objects from %s/%s to %s/%s.",
        objects.getObjectSummaries().size(), srcBucket, srcPath, destBucket, destPath));

final ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
for (final S3ObjectSummary summary : objects.getObjectSummaries()) {

    final CopyObjectRequest request = new CopyObjectRequest(srcBucket, summary.getKey(), destBucket,
            FileUtility.getFilePath(summary.getKey(), destPath));
    metadata.setContentType(getContentType(destPath));
    request.setNewObjectMetadata(metadata);
    amazonS3.copyObject(request);
}
log.info(String.format("Copied %d objects.", objects.getObjectSummaries().size()));
```

}

Comment: Hi -- your question says that A and B are both in us-west-2, did you mean that one of them was in us-east-1 (or another region)?

Comment: If you are working with buckets in different regions or accounts, you need to create a S3Client for each.

Comment: yes, right us-east-1

Comment: I don't understand the region error with buckets as the aws interface shows that s3 buckets are global. I don't even see a region in the s3 interface for buckets.